# how to make producer and consumer threads run interleaving

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I thought if I use pthread and spawn two threads, they would run interleaving, meaning that the execution would be something similar to:

```
producer

producer

consumer

consumer

producer

consumer

//both producer and consumer finish
```

However, what I'm getting now is

```
producer

producer

producer 

//producer finished

consumer

consumer

consumer

//consumer finished
```

I was wondering was this supposed to be happening or it looked like I did something wrong? How can I achieve the desire execution sequence?

Comment: Why should they interleave?

Comment: Can't answer any of those questions unless you show your code.

Comment: What would be the point if they interleaved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The threads would be scheduled independent of each other.Unless you use a mechanism to interleave them(mutex).